# Create a transparent layer with Stamen in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium, folium-plugins

I'm trying to create a map using Folium in Python, and I would need to do the following:
I have a geojson that contains the outline of Spain (or of a country or a municipality in Spain), and I want that when creating the map, the Stamen layer that is not inside the geojson (or the country's outline) appears blurred, transparent, or with a white layer, while what is inside my polygon is perfectly visible with the Stamen layer.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your geojson to the inverse.

Create a really big rectangle encompassing the whole world consisting of 2 shapes that combined have a hole that is your starting contour.

In the starting contour find the most top and bottom geo points.

Create shape 1:

- start at north pole
- go to top geo point
- add points of contour going clockwise until you reach bottom geo point
- go to south pole
- go west to the date marker line (180 east)
- close the shape

Create shape 2:

- start at south pole
- go to bottom geo point
- add points of contour going clockwise until you reach top geo point
- go to north pole
- go east to the date marker line (180 west)
- close the shape

Use this new geojson to color these regions white on the map.